# Running mocha test with Azure pipelines and Docker

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, continuous-integration, mocha.js

I am very new to CICD.

I have an Azure web app running a Docker container built from an Express Nodejs image.

My current flow is minimalistic. I have an Azure-pipelines.yml file that looks like

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'    

- task: AzureCLI@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az acr build --registry registry123 --image image123:latest --file Dockerfile .'
```

And a dockerfile that looks like

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /poc/microservices

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Now I have added some mocha tests that I can run with `npm test`, and these are running fine locally.

Now I want to add these to the pipeline so that it doesnt build the image if the tests are failing.

I have a mocha.opts file where I defined `--reporter mocha-junit-reporter` and the tests are using an `process.env.ENDPOINT` variable.

So my question is how do I add the command to the pipeline?

Do I simply add

```
- script: npm install
- script: npm test
```

to azure-pipelines.yml and then configure the ENDPOINT variable in the build variables in azure devOps portal?

If so, is it not a problem that I am running then twice `npm install`? once in Azure, and another time in Docker?

Answer (score 0):

Running NPM install twice would only slows your deployment and would not cause any other problems if you don't copy *node_modules* into your Docker container.

Make sure you copy only the source code to the docker container and leave *node_modules* out. You can add a *.dockerignore* file for that:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
```

This would make sure the packages are installed properly in the Docker container.